# Create variable gradient within SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, linear-gradients

Is it possible to create a variable gradient with SVG objects? Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a a horizontal bar chart and I want to apply shading to it. So the top most bar would have the most shading, and the bar after that less shading and so on. However, the number of bars is variable.

I don't want to create a gradient for every bar (plus with a variable number of bars thats hard), what I would like to do is use one gradient for each bar. In the selectall statement, can I edit the gradient that is in the def section? Something like:

`.attr("stop-color", function(d,i) "rgb("+50*i+","+50*i+","+50*i+")")"`?

I think I need to reference the name of the gradient somewhere. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to have a gradient that applies across a group of objects, then yes. That is possible.  You just have to define the gradient with absolute coordinates.  To do that, use `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`.

Below I am defining a gradient that starts at (0,0) and goes to (0,400).  All objects that fall betwee y=0 and y=400 will be drawn using an appropriate part of that gradient.

```html
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="mygradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="400">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  
  
  <g fill="url(#mygradient)" stroke="black" stroke-width="4">

    <rect x="5" y="5" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="105" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="205" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="305" width="390" height="90"/>

  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.